# django urlencode filter

Tags: python, django, urlencode

I have a problem with encoding urls using build-in django urlencode filter. When I use it on default django server everything is fine. But on apache2 it doesn`t work, ie. i have a tag called C#. On localhost my url is encoded to ...tags/C%23/ but on apache2 it is tags/C/

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a bug with [apache](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34602), simplest solution would be do url encoding twice or do a base64 encoding.

Comment: It is unlikely to be apache.  Apache does not change the HTML in a page.

Comment: I don't think he is talking about HTML in a page. He is talking about this happening in url.